# What was the difference between Number and Magnitude in Ancient Greece

Tags: calculus, ancient-greece, numbers

I've been reading *Infinite Powers* by *Steven Strogatz* and in it, he writes about how the greeks differentiated between numbers as being discrete and magnitudes as being continuous. However, all of these terms go over my head. What does he mean by discrete? What were magnitudes to the greeks? And can someone elaborate more on the difference between number and magnitude from the lens of the ancient greeks.

Thank you!

Comment: Discrete like integers - you know 2 comes after 1 and so on.

Comment: Discrete: $1,2,3,4\dots$ as opposed to continuous, including $2/3$ and $\sqrt{2}$ and $\pi$ and many others.

Comment: Does Discrete mean having finite amount of digits? As there are finite amount of digits in Integers; and does continuous mean having infinite digits? As there are infinite amount of digits in pi and root 2?

Comment: And see I. Grattan-Guinness, [Numbers, Magnitudes, Ratios, and Proportions in Euclid's Elements: How Did He Handle Them? (1966)](https://www.tau.ac.il/~corry/teaching/toldot/download/IGG.pdf)

Comment: If we suppose philosophy of mathematics had not changed radically between Greeks and Euler, we can read in his Algebra:
"First, everything will be said to be a magnitude, which is capable of increase or diminution, or to which something may be added or substracted .... mathematics is nothing more than the science of magnitudes, which finds methods by which they can be measured."
There was a belief that mathematics was the study of numerical magnitudes and spatial ones. Numbers then are discrete magnitudes.